# MenuStrip control menu's location change when form size getting smaller

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, menustrip

I have menustrip control in my Windows Form like this:

```
FILE EDIT VIEW OPTIONS ABOUT UPDATE
```

but when user changes the size of form and when form is getting narrow menus should be like this:

```
FILE EDIT VIEW OPTIONS
ABOUT UPDATE
```

Is there any property for this? Or should I use other control which makes possible what I want.
You can try it in Visual studio's dynamic Menu according to the window's size.

Any suggestions?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `LayoutStyle` property of your MenuStrip to `Flow`.